# Efficiently reshuffling a long matrix into one consisting of column bound subblocks (of the original) in R

Tags: r, matrix, dimension

"I have a very long matrix, measuring 30^5 x 3 entries. I basically consists of subblocks of 10.000 30 x 3 matrices, stacked on top of one another. I want to afficiently "cbind" them, next to one another (without looping constructs), leading to a 30 x 30^4 matrix.

Just changing the matrix dimensions does not work, as R fills the new matrix per individual column.

I'm sure there is a very compact, superefficient way of doing this, and I'll slap myself on the forehead as soon as you fill me in on the obvious solution.

Thanks!"

"Just changing the matrix dimensions does not work, as R fills the new matrix per individual column."

````
```R
test <- matrix(c(1:18), 6, 3, byrow = FALSE)

>test   
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    7   13
[2,]    2    8   14
[3,]    3    9   15
[4,]    4   10   16
[5,]    5   11   17
[6,]    6   12   18

dim(test) <- c(3,6)

>test
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18
```
````

The output I'm looking for is:
    `[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    [1,]    1    7   13    4   10   16
    [2,]    2    8   14    5   11   17
    [3,]    3    9   15    6   12   18`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a grouping variable to split the sequence of rows, subset the matrix and then `cbind`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(test)), 
       as.integer(gl(nrow(test), 3, nrow(test)))), function(i) test[i,]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    7   13    4   10   16
#[2,]    2    8   14    5   11   17
#[3,]    3    9   15    6   12   18
```

Comment: Great. This highly condensed code already solved my problem. Very efficient. Thanks again!!!